# xsd : element with unique value

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm working on xml and xsd, and i have several different elements in my xsd, and among all element i would like that some of them are unique.

here an example of my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LIST xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <PRODUCT>
        <TYPE>SecurityGateway</TYPE>
        <PRIMARY_IP>192.168.0.23</PRIMARY_IP>
        <PRIMARY_SUBNET_MASK>255.255.0.0</PRIMARY_SUBNET_MASK>
        <PRIMARY_PORT>443</PRIMARY_PORT>
        <SECONDARY_IP>192.168.0.66</SECONDARY_IP>
        <SECONDARY_SUBNET_MASK>255.255.128.0</SECONDARY_SUBNET_MASK>
        <SECONDARY_PORT>443</SECONDARY_PORT>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <TYPE>SecurityGateway</TYPE>
        <PRIMARY_IP>192.168.0.66</PRIMARY_IP>
        <PRIMARY_SUBNET_MASK>255.255.0.0</PRIMARY_SUBNET_MASK>
        <PRIMARY_PORT>443</PRIMARY_PORT>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <TYPE>SecurityGateway</TYPE>
        <PRIMARY_HOST_NAME>xx.yy.zz</PRIMARY_HOST_NAME>
        <PRIMARY_PORT>443</PRIMARY_PORT>
    </PRODUCT>
</LIST>
```

I would like to have an xsd which detect if an IP address is present more than once doesn't matter if it is in the PRIMARY_IP or SECONDARY_IP.
As you can see, in my xml, the product 1 as its PRIMARY_IP equal to the SECONDARY_IP of the product 2 -> I want to refuse this kind of xml because it is not possible that two product share the same IP.

Here an extract of my xsd :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:simpleType name="_IPv4Address">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="(([1]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([1]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="_Hostname">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="1" />
            <xs:maxLength value="255" />
            <xs:pattern value="([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])(\.([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]))*"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:element name="LIST">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <!-- details of each product element -->
                <xs:element name="PRODUCT" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="TYPE" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                            </xs:element>
                            <!-- Either product is accessible by static IP or by hostname -->
                            <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="PRIMARY_IP" type="_IPv4Address">
                                    </xs:element>
                                    <xs:element name="PRIMARY_SUBNET_MASK" type="_IPv4Address">
                                    </xs:element>
                                    <xs:element name="PRIMARY_PORT" type="xs:unsignedShort" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:sequence>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="PRIMARY_HOST_NAME" type="_Hostname">
                                    </xs:element>
                                    <xs:element name="PRIMARY_PORT" type="xs:unsignedShort" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:choice>
                            
                            <!-- Product can also have a secondary IP or  hostname -->
                            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="SECONDARY_IP" type="_IPv4Address">
                                    </xs:element>
                                    <xs:element name="SECONDARY_SUBNET_MASK" type="_IPv4Address">
                                    </xs:element>
                                    <xs:element name="SECONDARY_PORT" type="xs:unsignedShort">
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:sequence>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="SECONDARY_HOST_NAME" type="_Hostname">
                                    </xs:element>
                                    <xs:element name="SECONDARY_PORT" type="xs:unsignedShort">
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:choice>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Thank you for your help.

I try to add this in my xsd, but it doesn't work because it only compare the value for the "same" element:

```
<xs:unique name="uniquePRIMARY_IP">
    <xs:selector xpath="PRODUCT"/>
    <xs:field xpath="PRIMARY_IP"/>
</xs:unique>
<xs:unique name="uniquePRIMARY_Hostname">
    <xs:selector xpath="PRODUCT"/>
    <xs:field xpath="PRIMARY_HOST_NAME"/>
</xs:unique>
<xs:unique name="uniqueSECONDARY_IP">
    <xs:selector xpath="PRODUCT"/>
    <xs:field xpath="SECONDARY_IP"/>
</xs:unique>
<xs:unique name="uniqueSECONDARY_HOSTNAME">
    <xs:selector xpath="PRODUCT"/>
    <xs:field xpath="SECONDARY_HOST_NAME"/>
</xs:unique>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a uniqueness constraint (at the level of the `LIST` element) with `<selector path="PRODUCT/PRIMARY_IP | PRODUCT/SECONDARY_IP"/>` and `<field path="."/>`